# Triple integration, Spherical coordinates

Tags: calculus, transformation

How do we get limit such as $0\le\theta\le\pi$, $0\le\phi\le2\pi$ in spherical coordinate system where $$x=r \sin\theta\cos\phi, y=r \sin\theta\sin\phi, z=r \cos\theta$$ 
Why is the $\theta$-limit $[0,\pi]$ and not $2 \pi$?  I think that the angle of the foot of perpendicular from the point taken in spherical coordinate can lie within $[0,2 \pi]$

Answer (score 1):

You will be counting points more than once if you choose your angle like that (just take a sphere and walk over it using your angles and you will see what I mean). For example,
\begin{align}
(0,0,r)&=(r\sin(0)\cos(0),r\sin(0)\sin(0),r\cos(0))\\
&=(r\sin(2\pi)\sin(0),r\sin(2\pi)\cos(0),r\cos(2\pi)).
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$\theta$ is the angular distance from the north pole of the sphere. It shouldn't be more than $\pi$, because once you've gone past the south pole, you should be measuring along the opposite meridian instead (that is, with $\phi\pm\pi$.